# Dynamic UITextfield doesnt respond to keyboard inputs

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

HI all below is the code i am using, the textField is created in .h file and when i run the code the text field doesnt respond to keyboard( no letters typed are visible) also when i click Done on keybpard it does not trigger textfieldshouldreturn method. please help!!!

```
UIActionSheet *aac =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"New list item" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIDatePicker *theDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,100.0,0.0,0.0)];
self.textField=[[UITextField alloc] init];
self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25);
[self.textField setDelegate:self];
self.textField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;

[aac addSubview:textField];
[aac addSubview:theDatePicker];

[textField release];
[theDatePicker release];

UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
closeButton.momentary=YES;
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(270, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor =[UIColor blackColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[aac addSubview:closeButton];
[closeButton release];
[aac showInView:self.view];
[aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 685)];
```

Comment: You are displaying only the text filed in the action sheet?

Comment: tried only textfield and had same problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `self.` from before textField? If you have defined it in your header, as well as used @property, and @synthesize in your .m, you should be good. Also, make sure you have the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in your interface.

Comment: First off, where is your code placed? What scope? Second, what does your header look like? Can you provide more code of the header, because what you have provided looks correct enough, besides the "self."'s.

Comment: //here is header
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TEST : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate> {

 UITextField *textField;
 
 
 
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *textField;

@end

Comment: #import "TEST.h"


@implementation TEST

@synthesize textField;

Comment: and you removed the "self." from the other textFields in your code? It looks like from your question that the DONE button takes effect, if it hadn't, then your keyboard would show "RETURN".

Comment: -(void)showActionSheet {
 
 
 //code sits here
 
 
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 [self showActionSheet];
}

Comment: YES I got rid of all self's. my keyboard does show Done but instead of return but it doesn't trigger textfieldshouldreturn delegate, also no characters are visible while i type and it works when i copy paste text from outside. keyboard does respond by zooming characters i click.

Comment: try renaming the textField to something else, there may be a name conflict.

Comment: changed it to textField1 and also removed everything and leaving just textfield1 but no use.

Comment: can you send me a sample of your project? aaron@wrightscs.com. Theres got to be something very minuscule going on that we are missing.

Comment: I have sent you the project. have you received it?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem; My textfield did bring up the keyboard when I touched it, but no letters appeared in the textfield when tapping on the keyboard.

In my case I had been messing with the `AppDelegate.m` and removed the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`. So putting it back again (in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) solved it for me.